# How to make background color without using <canvas id>

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am a beginner at HTML, and CSS, and I am making a website using HTML. When I look at my site, the background is default white, and when I use #canvas {
background-color:black;
}
in CSS, it does not work, so how do you change the background color without using that method. I would really appreciate any answer that is given, Thank You.

Comment: If the answer works for you then you should tick it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems as though you may be confused about the use of the word 'canvas' in HTML. A canvas tag specifies a very particular type of element, on on which we can draw using e.g. avaScript. I think you are wanting to change the background of your whole content. In that case it's probably body you want to change the background of.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple as declaring the body tag in css like this

```css
body            
{
    margin:auto;
    width:1024px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
```